# Python print Class by list index and list string

Tags: python, string, list, class, indexing

```
my_list = ["David", "Beckham"]
class User:
 def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
my_list[0] = User(my_list[0], my_list[1])
```

#these works

```
print(my_list[0].firstname)
print(my_list[0].lastname)
```

#What I want is this. But it makes error. Can I make it?

```
print("David".lastname)
print("David".firstname)
```

Answer (score 1):

About the code below. "David" is a string and it does not have the attributes lastname and first name

```
print("David".lastname)
print("David".firstname)
```

But you can create an instance of User like:

```
david = User(my_list[0], my_list[1])
print(david.lastname)
print(david.firstname)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are asking is not possible. But you can achieve a little same using dictionary. Here is the code

```
my_list = ["David", "Beckham"]
class User:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.vals={}
        self.vals[self.firstname]=self.lastname
        
    def get(self):
        return self.vals

u = User(my_list[0], my_list[1])
lastname=u.get()
print(lastname["David"])
```